# Fragment menu calling activity menu

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity menu and on one fragment I want to replace an item inside that menu. The item when pressed launches an activity.  My fragment menu item works, but it also calls the activity menu item intent. I need to remove the duplicate main activity menu item being selected too.

Main Activity menu:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


       else if(itemId == R.id.action_settings)

            startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PreferencesActivity.class));

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Fragment menu:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),
                        PreferencesFragment.class));
                return false;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only if the activity doesn't use the action that it is passed to the fragment. You may be able to add in the activity a boolean that causes the switch to be bypassed for that item.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (!isMyFragmentPresent()) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PreferencesActivity.class));
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public void setMyFragmentIsPresent(boolean isMyFragmentPresent) {
    this.isMyFragmentPresent = isMyFragmentPresent;
}
```

UPDATE: I realise this doesn't work if you have more items than the one you want to change. Maybe you would be better having a default Fragment that loads in the activity that does nothing but load the R.id.action_settings settings button and what it does. This fragment would then be replaced by your new Fragment.